# Dynamically preset a url for development and production environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm creating a password reset functionality for my site in rails and in my mailer `password_reset.text.erb` file I'm currently sending

`http://localhost:3000/password_resets/<%=@user.password_reset_token%>/edit/`

in my development environment. This will hit my controller for password reset and redirect the user to edit the password if the token matches with the saved model.

However, I'd like to configure this dynamically so when I deploy to heroku it will know to change that to `mywebsite.com/password_resets/...`

How would I do this?

EDIT:

```
def password_reset(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: user.email, subject: "Bitelist Password Reset")
end
```

Comment: Are you using typical ActionMailer calls to send email?

Comment: yes see my `password_reset` in my `UserMailer` above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically I configure the host information for the mailer in an appropriate `config/environment` file.

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "example.com" }
```

You can take a look at the "Generating URLs" section of this page: http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html

With that configuration set typical routing structures seem to work quite nicely. I am not 100% positive what routes will be available in your situation so you may still need to construct the full URL somewhat manually to include the reset token component.

To generate the actual URLs you can potentially use named routes if your routes are set up in a way that you have a named route that takes a user token. i.e.

```
<%= edit_password_resets_url(@user.password_reset_token) %>
```

If you do not have the token integrated into an existing route you may need to manually build the URL:

```
<%= "#{url_for(:controller => 'password_resets', :action => 'whatever_action_this_is')}/#{@user.password_reset_token}/edit/" %>
```

or even build it completely manually using `default_url_options[:host]` and then add the rest that you have above.

If need be you could also set the host at request time although that may be overkill (and will not be thread safe).

```
def set_mailer_host
  ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = request.host_with_port
end
```

Comment: I should also note I have never used Heroku before so there may be a more appropriate Heroku-specific solution out there.

Comment: so in `development.rb` I should have `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost:3000" }` and in `production.rb` I should have `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "website.com" }` ?

Comment: I believe there is a separate `:port` option you can use to specify the 3000, but otherwise yes something like that.

Comment: so then what can i put in the mailer view?

Comment: Edited the answer to include some possible approaches. It really depends on how your routing is set up.

Comment: I was guessing what a named helper for one of your routes might look like. You should probably read through this to get a better sense of routing in rails: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Yeah I tried the actual name of the route path...not sure why it's doing that.

Comment: Did you remember to add `_url` to the method? i.e. `edit_password_resets_url`

I noticed that I forgot that in my answer, which is now updated.